# Getting a double slash when redirecting for a canonical hostname on Firefox only (Django)

Tags: django, apache, firefox, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi

I have a Django powered website, and I'm trying to solve the "canonical hostname" problem. I want www.example.com to redirect to example.com. I have tried both techniques found in the [Apache documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) (scroll down to Canonical hostnames).

I'm currently trying the mod_rewrite method, and I have this in a virtual host container:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

This works for me, except for one case. In Firefox only, if I type `www.example.com` in a browser, it redirects and I see this in the URL bar: `example.com//` (note the 2 trailing slashes).

However, something like this will work correctly: `www.example.com/news/` gets redirected to `example.com/news/`.

I only see this on the root URL in Firefox. It seems to work fine on Windows under Chrome, IE9, and Opera (maybe those browsers eat the double slash?). My Mac using friend says it is fine in Safari, but he also sees the problem in Firefox.

As far as Django settings go, I am using the default value of `APPEND_SLASH=True`. I don't know if Django has anything to do with it, but I've tried mod_rewrite rules like the above on static HTML sites before and it always seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This magically stopped happening, so I am going to assume there was a problem with Firefox at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Try to ignore the "/" by putting it into parenthesis, so, wheter it's here or not, the last part should work (and this is not $1 anymore but $2 in the redirection URL):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*)$ http://example.com/$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Please tell me if it works.